# SQL Server Codeigniter - How to use the current row&column value as the parameter in the other column?

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, codeigniter

i have some trouble in my SQL database queries.

Assume I have 2 queries, query 1, and query 2

Query 1 result is :

```
ID      Name
1       Soap
2       Spoon
3       Fork
4       Toothpaste
```

In the query 2 I need to get the ID from query 1 to get the price, so the result in the third column is dependent with the ID/first column

```
ID      Name       Price
1       Soap       10000
2       Spoon      20000
3       Fork       30000
4       Toothpaste 40000
```

My query :

```
SELECT t.ID, s.NAME FROM TRANSACTION t, STOCK s WHERE s.ID=t.ID
```

and I wanna change that query like this

```
SELECT t.ID, s.NAME, ????? FROM TRANSACTION t, STOCK s WHERE s.ID=t.ID
```

Comment: can you explain `to get the price, so the result in the third column is dependent with the ID/first column`

Comment: next time try to provide a 
  [**SqlFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/5368b/6) with a schema and some data so we can understand the problem better and give you an answer 
   much faster – Also please read [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 
   And [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza this is an example, the price here is calculated by selecting the sum of quantity * price

Comment: There isnt a `quantity` column

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to join the two tables `Stock` and `Transaction` to get the the `Price` which you said was equal to the `sum of quantity * price` for each item in `Stock`.

You can do this:

```
SELECT s.[ID], s.[Name], SUM(t.Price) as [Price]
FROM [STOCK] s
LEFT JOIN [TRANSACTION] t ON s.[ID] = t.[ID]
GROUP BY s.[ID], s.[Name]
ORDER BY s.[ID] ASC
```

This will get all the `Stock` items and sum the respective values in the `Transaction` table.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you already have what you are looking for, just add the last column: **s.Price**

```
SELECT t.ID, s.Name, s.Price
FROM TRANSACTION t, STOCK s
WHERE s.ID = t.ID
```